AVG antivirus quarantines Bitcoin-Qt
I verified the Bitcoin Core V28 (MacOS) download using the usual recommended methods, but my antivirus software detects "malware" with the attached message. Is this normal, and should I be concerned? Is there a way to bypass this as otherwise I can't run Bitcoin Core on my machine? Any help to get me started would be great.


Is there a way to bypass this

AVG says

Open AVG Antivirus and go to ☰ Menu ▸ Settings.
Select General ▸ Exceptions, then click Add exception.
Read through the questions to ask and click Next ▸ I understand risks.
Add an exception in one of the following ways:

Type the specific file/folder path or URL into the text box, then click Add exception.
Click Browse, tick the box next to the file or folder, then click OK ▸ Add exception.


Your specified file, folder, or website is added to the exceptions list.


Cool! Thanks, I followed your advice and voila, it worked. Good to know :)
